# Highlight a buffer with custom programming language syntax

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I have files which are not .py but they are python code. I want to highlight them as if they were python files. How can I do that.

Comment: Simplest thing to do is to switch modes using `M-x python-mode`. That'll set up highlighting, indentation, keybindings, etc.

Comment: If the files have a particular file extension or path component that is unique to them, you can add them to ‘auto-mode-alist’ to have them automatically open up on python mode.

Comment: they do have extensions like .bzl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file extension is `.bzl`, then you can do this:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.bzl\\'" . python-mode))
```